# Post request did not send data as expected

Tags: python, json, post, request, web-crawler

I've tried to crawl data form a website and code in Python. But my post request that I wrote didn't send back the data that I expected.

This is the code that I wrote

```py
import requests
import json
url = "example.com/api/something"

headers = { 
    'Host': 'example.com',
    'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=RANDOMID',
    'Content-Length': '11',
    'Accept-Language': 'en',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile':'?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.5735.110 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '""',
    'Origin': 'example.com',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'example.com/home',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'close'
}
payload = "SomeRandomID"
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps({payload:''}))
print(r.content)
```

The code printed

```json
{'code': '0', 'msg': 'done', 'data': None, 'sign': ''}
```

, what it supposed to be

```json
{'code': '0', 'msg': 'done', 'data': [JSON TYPE DATA], 'sign': ''}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're sending a `Content-Type: application/json` header, thus promising that your request will send json, but the request is NOT actually sending json.

Comment: In any case, json or not, your question is about how a specific API ought to behave, which we can't answer.  You'll have to ask the API provider.

Comment: All the headers was originally from the _browser_, I just copied them in the code. I tried several type of payload but the status code is 200 only when I used `json.dumps()` for the payload.

Comment: Okay, so maybe it's fine to use that header, but then your code should **actually send json**, which it is not doing.

Comment: Thanks for your opion. May I ask how can I send *json* in the post request?

Comment: Somehow I successfully get the data I wanted. What I change in the code is payload = ' "SomeRandomId" '

Comment: To send json, use the `json=` argument, not `data=`.